# How to get logs of every action from every user?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I would like to get the logs of every user activity.

- Every link or button a user clicks.
- Every page a user visits.
- Every transaction, action a user does.

All of the activities from every user.

Is there a module or feature in Odoo version 14 CE that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people use the free module 'Audit Log' https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/auditlog/

There are many other apps available to download in the odoo app store.  I would search for the term 'audit'.
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/sh_user_audit/
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/browse?search=audit